# The method is not allowed for the requested URL. (Flask+Javascript)

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am working on Flask and not able to resolve this error. I think the problem is in preventDefault() method but I can't figure it out. I can't see the output of any of my javaScript.

Python-

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    locations = sorted(data['location'].unique())
    return render_template('index.html', locations=locations)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET' ,'POST'])
def predict():
    location = request.form.get('location')
    bhk = request.form.get('BHK')
    bath = request.form.get('bath')
    sqft = request.form.get('sqft')
    bhk = float(bhk)
    bath = float(bath)
    sqft = float(sqft)

    input =pd.DataFrame([location, sqft, bath, bhk], columns=['location', 'total_sqft', 'bath', 'bhk'])
    prediction = pipe.predict(input)[0]

    return str(prediction)
```

Below is the Javascript for my project. If CSS is also needed please let me know, I will update my post.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                function form_handler(event){
                    event.preventDefault()
                   }
                function send_data()
                {
                    document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",
        form_handler);
        
                    var fd=new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
        
                    var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
        
                    xhr.open('POST', '/predict', true);
                    document.getElementByID("prediction").innerHTML = "PLEASE WAIT...";
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
                            document.getElementByID("prediction").innerHTML = "Prediction: Rs. "+ xhr.responseText;
                }
                };
                xhr.onload = function(){};
                xhr.send(fd);
                }
</script>
```

Comment: When did you call `send_data`?

Comment: That function is actually called on button click. Here's the github link of complete project, if you wanna check out- https://github.com/Hrithik-Nigam/House-price-prediction

Comment: I tried your code (cloned from github) with Python 3.7.9: it didn't work at first, but after I moved `index.html` to `templates/index.html` then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this conditional statement in the first line of your predict route

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Unfortunately, it's not working. I added the condition inside the definition of the predict function, I am guessing that's what you suggested?